# Create a variable that is reachable from all view controllers

Tags: swift, firebase

I want to save a variable that is reachable from all view controllers and files. What do I need to do to complete that?

I have a text field that creates input "email"
and have to keep that, so when info is added, it goes to the database with the file name (email/username).

Comment: Use `AppDelegate`.

Comment: You're not using Firebase Auth?

Comment: In other way, maybe also you can use [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults)

Comment: Where there are a couple of answers suggesting a singleton pattern - it's debatable if that's actually the *best* solution based on the entire question. Why is the question tagged Firebase? what are you doing with the email address - is that stored in your firebase as a key? If so, you may want to consider using the uid of the user to store their 'stuff', which can always be retrieved with `let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid'. Perhaps some more information about your use case would reveal an appropriate answer. (Singletons are fine by me but it may not fit this use case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razi Singleton approach is pretty nice. I will leave another one particularly used in swift called struct:

```
struct UserData {
    static var email = "hi@contact.com"
}
```

So you can use anywhere in your app :)

```
//Read/Write
UserData.email = "somethingElse"
```

In the future, look furthermore about this topic as "Global Variables" and the better approaches of it, specially when it comes to security and data persistence.

Comment: I am not sure this is the best answer to the actual question. While on the surface, it seems the question is how to store a global var, I don't believe that's what the OP is after. I think what they want is to is to have a consistent *key* to store user data in Firebase; and they want to use an email address. A better solution is to have that stored in their Firebase User object .currentUser property. Additionally, there are challenges with using an email address as a key (illegal characters, email addresses change etc) so there are better options for generating a unique key (uid).

Answer (score 2):

> Use `Singleton` Pattern

```
class EmailManager {
    static let shared = EmailManager()

    var email: String
}
```

Save Data as

```
EmailManager.shared.email = textField.text!
```

Read it as from anywhere

```
let email = EmailManager.shared.email
```